# Problem with image field crop

Tags: 7, entities

I have a problem with the module image field crop.  I upload an image and I can to crop but when I am going to edit the node to change the crop of the image, I can't. When I edit a node, I only see the cropped image. To change the crop area I need to remove the image and upload the original image again.  Is not it possible to edit the crop for the images?

Comment: This sounds like a good question for the module's issue queue

Comment: Take a look at [#719714: Collapsed fieldgroups break crop area display](http://drupal.org/node/719714). There are some patches available there that might help you resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried the patches and I didn't work well.  However, I saw the problem is related with the image field into fieldset.

Comment: I found this patch, it works for me in localhost and resolve the problem with the image crop and fieldsets: http://drupal.org/files/issues/imgfld_crop_fieldset.patch Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an issue that should be reported in the project issue queue on drupal.org.